# Adaptar código JS para IE8 e IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Como posso fazer esse código abaixo funcionar no IE8 e IE9, porque ele funciona apenas no 10

```
$("#input_file").change( function(event) {
    var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);

    $("img").attr('src',tmppath);

});
```

### Método que não funciona

```
URL.createObjectURL
```

Qualquer coisa já ajuda(bibliotecas, scripts e etc)

Comment: Olá, qual método ou objeto que não funciona no IE8 e 9 ?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa Editei!

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha já testaste isto: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11277737/2256325 ?

Comment: @Sergio, não tinha visto.. mas mesmo assim infelizmente ainda não resolve 100% do problema porque no IE 9 ainda não funciona

Comment: Acho que nos IEs anteriores ao 10 não tem jeito mesmo.

Comment: Para que serve esse método?

Comment: Pois como o @bfavaretto referiu isso não vai dar. O que queres fazer? fazer preview de imagens? Algo como isto: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4459379/2256325 ?

Comment: cara eu nem sei o que usar para isso funcionar. o IE é um atraso de vida. Não serve para absolutamente nada. Na verdade serve só para dar problemas

Comment: Respeito sua opinião, porém realmente existem situações em que o cliente exige que o sistema funcione (às vezes até exclusivamente) no IE, inclusive empresas multinacionais.

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha você quer apenas fazer um "preview" da imagem?

Comment: Eu não cheguei a trabalhar com o IE 10, portanto desconheço esse método. Imagino que terá que fazer uma função para verificar qual a versão do IE do cliente e se for versão anterior ao IE 10, trabalhar de outra forma. Dependendo do seu objetivo, exista uma forma que se aplique às versões anteriores e atual.

Comment: Só como complemento estou em um projeto para uma grande empresa que para homologá-lo precisa rodar no IE8. Então, infelizmente, o gosto pessoal não serve como parâmetro nem norteador.

Comment: Achei isso no Stack Overflow Inglês.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206127/createobjecturl-does-not-work-in-ie10
Olhe se pode te ajudar.

Comment: Esta questão está resolvida?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo não.

Comment: É possível instalar algo no computador? Tipo um servidor... ou então o Flash no browser?

Answer (score 1):

### Biblioteca mOxie

Achei uma biblioteca capaz de fazer o que você está pedindo.
Trata-se de um [polyfill listado no GitHub do modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#file-api) chamado **[mOxie](https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie)**.
A biblioteca é fantástica, exceto para se iniciar o desenvolvimento. Tive de compilar ela, para depois começar a testar... ai corrigi uns erros de compilação, e uns erros no JavaScript gerado, ai finalmente funcionou.

Usei as seguintes partes do mOxie:

- [FileInput](https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie/wiki/FileInput): componente que permite selecionar um arquivo e utilizar os arquivo que forem selecionados usando um `FileReader`
- [FileReader](https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie/wiki/FileReader): permite ler um arquivo
- [Image](https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie/wiki/Image): permite manipular imagens, tal como redimensioná-la

Pela dificuldade que tive na compilação, resolvi criar um repositório no GitHub com a versão já compilada:

- [mOxie-Compiled](https://github.com/masbicudo/mOxie-Compiled) dentro da pasta `\v1.2.1\dist`

### Exemplo de uso

Coloquei na pasta `\v1.2.1\samples`, o exemplo de como fazer o que você falou:

- `image-preview-before-upload.htm`

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="moxie.min.js"></script>
      <script>mOxie.Env.swf_url = 'Moxie.swf';</script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          function readURL(input) {
              if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                  var reader = new mOxie.FileReader();
                  reader.onload = function (e) {
                      var img = new mOxie.Image();
                      img.onload = function() {
                          img.downsize({width:100});
                          var tgt = document.getElementById("target");
                          img.embed(tgt);
                      };
                      img.load(e.target.result);
                  };
                  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
              }
          }
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form id="form1">
          <div id="container">
              <a id="file-picker" href="javascript:;">Browse...</a>
          </div>

          <script>
              var fileInput = new mOxie.FileInput({
                  browse_button: 'file-picker', // or document.getElementById('file-picker')
                  container: 'container',
                  accept: [
                      {title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png"} // accept only images
                  ],
                  multiple: true // allow multiple file selection
              });

              fileInput.onchange = function(e) {
                  // do something to files array
                  //console.info(e.target.files); // or this.files or fileInput.files
                  readURL(this);
              };

              fileInput.init(); // initialize
          </script>
          <div id="target"></div>
      </form>
  </body></html>
  ```

### Compatibilidade

Funciona no **IE8**[image: ok] e **IE9**[image: ok]. Também no **Chrome**[image: ok], **FireFox**[image: ok] e **Opera**[image: ok].

Tive problema com o **Safari**[image: fail], **IE6**[image: fail] e **IE7**[image: fail].

Talvez o melhor seja usar uma abordagem seletiva entre a minha resposta, o seu próprio código (deve funcionar no Safari), e a [resposta do @CarlosMartins](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53341/1925) (que usa AlphaImageLoader, pelo que pesquisei funciona no IE6 e IE7). Você poderia usar comentários condicionais para atingir a compatibilidade total se quiser.

### Dependências

Para funcionar no IE8 e IE9 o mOxie requer ou **Flash** ou **SilverLight**. Parece que eles possuem planos de suportar o uso de Java também, mas por enquanto não tem.

Answer (score 0):

A última vez que fiz eu acabei ocultando quando fosse o ie8

no seu caso faria mais ou menos assim:

```js
function createObjectURL ( file ) {
    if ( window.webkitURL ) {
        return window.webkitURL.createObjectURL( file );
    } else if ( window.URL && window.URL.createObjectURL ) {
        return window.URL.createObjectURL( file );
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

$("#input_file").change( function(event) {
    var tmppath = createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
 if(tmppath)
  $("img").attr('src',tmppath);
 else
  $("img").hide()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A solução para o teu problema penso que está [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8624388). Testei no IE7+ e funciona.

```
<style>
    #preview_ie {
        FILTER: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(sizingMethod=scale)
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="preview_ie">
    </div>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type='file' id="imgInp" onchange="readURL(this)" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function readURL(imgFile)
        {    
            var newPreview = document.getElementById("preview_ie");
            newPreview.filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = imgFile.value;
            newPreview.style.width = "160px";
            newPreview.style.height = "120px";
        }  
    </Script>
</body>
```